# Replace NA with zero when separating with tidyr?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a column of decimals in a tibble that I want to separate into the integer and non-integer components. If the part after the decimal point is exactly zero, then the `separate()` function turns it into `NA`.

```r
library("tidyverse") # or
# library("tibble")
# library("tidyr")

x <- c(1992.345, 1993.000, 1993.544)
y <- c(31.2, 32.3, 33.4)
dat <- tibble(x, y)

dat %>% 
  separate(x,
           into = c("x1", "x2"),
           convert = TRUE,
           fill = "right")

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      x1    x2     y
#>   <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1  1992   345  31.2
#> 2  1993    NA  32.3
#> 3  1993   544  33.4
```

I would like to tell `separate()` to retain the zero instead of replacing it with `NA`? I know that I can `mutate()` and `replace_na()`, e.g.

```r
dat %>% 
  separate(x,
           into = c("x1", "x2"),
           convert = TRUE,
           fill = "right") %>% 
  mutate(x2 = replace_na(x2, 0))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      x1    x2     y
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1992   345  31.2
#> 2  1993     0  32.3
#> 3  1993   544  33.4
```

**Question:** Can I skip the `mutate()` step and replace `NA` with zero in the `separate()` step? Or, is this about as concise as it can get? I am open to other solutions.

<sup>Created on 2018-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: You can make the `replace_na` a little more concise by not using `mutate`: `dat %>% separate(x, into = c("x1", "x2")) %>% replace_na(list(x2 = 0))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can format the `x` column before using the `separate` function.

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(x = format(x, nsmall = 3)) %>%
  separate(x,
           into = c("x1", "x2"),
           convert = TRUE,
           fill = "right")
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      x1    x2     y
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1  1992   345  31.2
# 2  1993     0  32.3
# 3  1993   544  33.4
```